# Expected Value of Drawing the number that matches the number of the draw

Tags: probability

Say there are 5 balls numbered 1 through 5 in a bin. You draw them out one at a time without replacement. Every time the number on the drawn ball matches the number of the draw, you win a dollar. (example: draw ball #3 on the third draw, you win a dollar for that draw) What is the expected amount of winnings?

So since expected value can be summed up even for conditional events, I thought that you can simply add (1/5)*1 + (1/4)*1 + (1/3)*1 + (1/2)*1 + (1/1)*1. This answer doesn't make sense logically (specifically when examining the last term and seeing an EV of 1), **but given that you can sum up conditional events when calculating EV, it should work, right?  Whis this wrong?**

The right answer is (1/5)*5 = $1.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Your mistake is this:

Suppose on the first draw you draw the ball numbered $2$. Then the probability of drawing ball number $2$ on the second draw is $0$, rather than $\frac{1}{4}$.  Similar for the third, fourth, and fifth draw.